# No errors but cannot remove a folder from a USD drive

Tags: 14.04, usb

I've checked for errors my external USD drive using GParted. Yet it seems there're some. For example, I can't delete a folder:

```
 sudo rm -rf  /media/me/MyDisk/.MyFolder
rm: cannot remove ‘/media/me/MyDisk/.MyFolder’: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try remounting the drive with read-write flag. Something like following should work.

## mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/me/MyDisk

Comment: mount: you must specify the filesystem type